# Knockout: set visibility base on attribute value in observable array

Tags: knockout.js, observable

Hi i want to be able to bind visibility of items in table base on value of array.

i have

```
<input type="text" value="2" data-bind="visible: this.arrayVal[2].name == 'RST'/>
```

and so on, i have Jquery to generate the data bind values. Is this  correct?

Also how do i initialize the value dynamically. Example of table of N rows, and i want to bind the value to an observable array of 10 rows?

So to clear up this is what i wrote since i have no control over the html, i am using Jquery to add data binding.

```
function addDataBind(index) {
   var selectItem, textItem;
   selectItem = $("#input" + index + "selectItem");
   textItem = $("#input" + index + "textItem");
   if (selectItem.length && textItem.length) {
        selectItem.attr("data-bind", "value: arrayVal[" + index + "], valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'"
        textItem.attr("data-bind", "visible: arrayVal[" + index + "] == 'RST'");
   }
}
```

using this.arrayVal()[$index] does not work in firefox but works in chrome. 
but using this.arrayVal[$index] works in both firefox and chrome.

Answer (score 0):

One of the main problems here seems to be that you're not referencing the observable array correctly, if `arrayVal` really is an observable array you would need to do:

```
<input type="text" value="2" data-bind="visible: this.arrayVal()[2].name == 'RST'"/>
```

To initialize the value attribute dynamically, you would need to do something like this:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: this.arrayVal">
    <input type="text" data-bind="visible: name == 'RST', value: $index"/>
</div>
```

This takes away the ugliness of referencing the array index directly in the view.